# How to suppress "ans" line from MATLAB output?

Tags: matlab

> **EDIT**: The question above concerns *strictly* to the output that MATLAB
>   produces by default ***in an interactive session***, as illustrated by
>   the given example.  I have ***no interest*** in ways to modify the
>   appearance of the output produced by scripts, functions, methods, etc.

Also, the motivation for this is to keep more of my laptop's *extremely* scarce "screen real estate" for *actually informative output*.

---

Even with `format compact`, MATLAB's output includes an `ans =` line in addition to the line(s) that show the output proper.  E.g.

```
>> format compact
>> date
ans =
04-Sep-2012
>>
```

Is there any way to suppress the `ans =` line, so that, e.g., the last interaction above looks like this?:

```
>> date
04-Sep-2012
>>
```

...or at least like this?:

```
>> date
ans = 04-Sep-2012
>>
```

Comment: Have you seen [this thread?](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/18502)

Comment: `disp(date)` does what you want

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bit tricky and might have other consequences, but if you are mainly displaying data of a certain type (double, char, etc.) you can overwrite the corresponding built-in display method.

For example,

```
>> % Before overwriting the @char/display
>> date
ans =
04-Sep-2012
```

Now create an `@char` directory in a location that is on MATLAB's path and add a method called `display.m`:

```
function display(x)
disp(x)
end
```

Then you would have

```
>> % After overwriting the @char/display
>> date
04-Sep-2012
```

Answer (score 3):

`ans` is merely the name of the variable in which MATLAB stores its "last" answer. The easiest way to "avoid it" would be simply to assign the result to some other variable and print it out, in a clear fashion, with `fprintf` or `sprintf`.

Answer (score 1):

`disp(sprintf('<Your format>',<variables>)` does that job.

Answer (score 0):

If you were creating a new class for your work, then you would have some options.  The "pretty" display on the command window is created by the `display` method which all classes inherit/  Generally, `display` prints the name of the variable, the " = \n" and then calls the `disp` method, which you are probably familiar with.  (`help display` for details).

However, for standard Matlab arrays, these methods are all built-ins, and I don't believe that they can be modified.

So, while you have endless options if you are building tools (`sprintf`, `fprintf`, `disp`, [various tools hacking the underlying java display](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/cprintf-display-formatted-color-text-in-command-window/)), I do not know of any way to setup a "more compact" display style as the default during quick, interactive work.