# Call previous answer- matlab

Tags: matlab

I know that I can put something such as

```
2+2
ans^2
```

But say for instance I wanted to call my answer from two entries ago.  In Mathematica, I could use `%%` but what is the equivalent (if any) in matlab?

Comment: i don't believe ans is a vector, as such it only stores the latest result

Comment: One workaround would be suppress `ans` from storing a command's "answer" using `disp()` or assigning to a different variable (as in [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12267865/how-to-suppress-ans-line-from-matlab-output)). Then you could use `ans` for old entries. But this is far from robust...

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that would be useful. Sadly, the "designers" of Matlab didn't consider that. The best that I can suggest is the the [commandhistory](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/commandhistory.html). It's not at all the same. You can also use the up ↑ and down ↓ arrows on your keyboard to page through your previous command window entries, but these are the commands themselves, not the answers. I think that best practice is to just get in the habit of not relying on `ans` and instead creating explicit variables in your workspace.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately that is what I figured.  Just thought I would see if anyone knew something I couldnt find.